# Response seems to get redirected if SQL injection query succeeds, if not then it doesn't get redirected

Tags: http, sql-injection, sqlmap

Under the authorization of my friend, I am testing his website against potential vulnerabilities.

I was trying to find if I was able to inject a SQL query into a POST request parameter `hi' or 1=1 --`:

```
query=hi'%20or%201%3d1%20--
```

I found that the document prints out:

```
<div class="error">index job,query: syntax error, unexpected '-' near '-'</div>
```

while with `' or 0=0 --` I get:

```
<div class="error">index job,query: syntax error, unexpected '|' near ' | 0=0) --'</div>
```

does this mean that it's vulnerable to SQL Injection? If yes, how can I make it print server system data (like information, etc.)? By the way, if the string is correct it gets redirected to another webpage (I think that's why SQLMap tells me the parameter is not SQL-injectable).

I can see the query works just if the URL gets redirected, but I won't see the query output. If the URL doesn't get redirected, I can see these SQL query errors. I'm trying to see how to get the output and do something more useful to attack the website, or even make it detectable from `sqlmap`.

The current command I'm using is `sqlmap -r thework.txt -p query --dbs`. `thework.txt` contains the full valid `POST` request.

Comment: Are you making sure to put a space after the two dashes? It's required for the rest of the line to be interpreted as a comment

Comment: Have you tried changing other settings with SQLMAP? E.g. level/risk